# How to get the record with the smallest date value

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as bellow which is a sceenshot of the laptops assigned to company employees! [image]

I need to query the laptop computers that are assigned to employee for the first time so that I know for how long the laptop has been used! something like:

```
2   2   1   J45C3R1      2011-11-24
2   2   2   99W33N1      2012-04-03
2   4   42  YKLK118944   2009-07-10
2   4   42  YKLK059498   2010--3-24
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: See many of the other questions tagged `greatest-n-per-group` for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT type_code,brand_code,model_code,serial_no, MIN(assign_date) 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY type_code,brand_code,model_code,serial_no
```

Comment: I had missed the group_by the all four columns!